# Cant round a number in Python

Tags: python, rounding

Im new to programming. I made a small program that tells you which  is the perfect TV(in inches) compared the disdance(in meters). Program should give rounded number without commas.

The code:

```
distance = int(input("Enter distance: "))

def tv_diagonal(x, y):
    tv_diagonal = x*y
    return round (tv_diagonal)
print(distance * tv_diagonal(100,0.39) / 2.5)
```

Please help. Im out of ideas.

Comment: Could you tell us what output you are getting and what output you are expecting?

Comment: That's the weirdest aspect ratio I've ever seen on a TV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to throw away the decimal use

```
print(int(distance * tv_diagonal(100,0.39) / 2.5))
```

If you want to round to the nearest integer use

```
print(round(distance * tv_diagonal(100,0.39) / 2.5))
```

If you are using python2 and want to round to the nearest integer but not have a decimal point use

```
print(int(round(distance * tv_diagonal(100,0.39) / 2.5)))
```

Comment: @mvelay, It is working for me. I'm using version 2.7.6, what is your full version and how did it fail?